# jquery html parent

Tags: jquery, css, methods, parent

Lets say I have this code:

```
<div class="user">
    <img class="profilepic" src="someimage.jps">
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
    [ <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="skip" Onclick="javascript:chg_background();">change bg</a> ]
    <div class="cleaner" style="padding-bottom: 5px;"></div>
</div>
```

How can i change div class="user" with red background, with jquery parent method or similar?

Thanks!

Guns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to walk back up the DOM tree:

```
function chg_background(el) {
    var $user = $(el).closest('.user');
    $user.css('background-color', '#f00');
}
```

And change the HTML to this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="skip" Onclick="javascript:chg_background(this);">change bg</a>
```

Or do it in a more traditional jQuery fashion:

```
$('#id').click(function() {
    var $user = $(this).closest('.user');
    $user.css('background-color', '#foo');
});
```

And drop the `onclick` attribute on the `#id` link.